# Как на front-end вывести поля ввода shipping из админки? (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как на странице (фронт) вывести поля ввода shiping price для товара?
На фронте есть страница создания товара (естественно для авторизированных пользователей). Нужно добавить еще поле ввода для методов shipping price(аналог админки, но только на фронте). Нашел как это реализовано в плагине   woocommerce в файле :

```
plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/setting/views/html-admin-page-shipping-zone-methods.php
```

Нужный мне блок реализован таким вот  образом:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-wc-modal-shipping-method-settings">
<div class="wc-backbone-modal wc-backbone-modal-shipping-method-settings">
    <div class="wc-backbone-modal-content">
        <section class="wc-backbone-modal-main" role="main">
            <header class="wc-backbone-modal-header">
                <h1><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( _x( '%s Settings', 'Shipping Method Settings', 'woocommerce' ), '{{{ data.method.method_title }}}' ) ); ?></h1>
                <button class="modal-close modal-close-link dashicons dashicons-no-alt">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Close modal panel', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </button>
            </header>
            <article class="wc-modal-shipping-method-settings">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {{{ data.method.settings_html }}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="instance_id" value="{{{ data.instance_id }}}" />
                </form>
            </article>
            <footer>
                <div class="inner">
                    <button id="btn-ok" class="button button-primary button-large"><?php _e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wc-backbone-modal-backdrop modal-close"></div>
```

Обычное copy-past на фронте не работает (кто бы сомневался), а код "{{{ data.method.settings_html }}}" выводит в виде строки. Такого синтаксиса я не видел и как он работает не могу понять. Объясните, пожалуста или подскажите - как еще можно вывести поля ввода shipping на вронте? Может с помощью хуков каких-то? 
(перелопатил все хуки со словом "shipping"-не нашел подходящего)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На фронте это осуществляется таким вот образом:

```
<?php $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones(); ?>

<?php foreach($delivery_zones[2]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) { ?>
    <?php  $zone_title = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $zone->title));   ?>

    <label>
        <?php echo $zone->title ?><span>*</span>
        <input  id="product_shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>"
                type="number" name="shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>"
                value="<?php echo $edit_action ? get_post_meta($product_id,'_ed_shipping_method_' . $zone_title, true) : ""; ?>"/>
    </label>
<?php } ?>
```